# Converting WordPerfect files with mail-merge logic to .docx

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, docx, wordperfect

I am working with a large number of `.frm` and `.wpd` WordPerfect files and I am trying to convert them to `.docx` while retaining all of the mail-merge logic.

Saving the files as `.docx` within WordPerfect X6 or opening the `.frm`/`.wpd` files from within Word 2016 both result in a complete loss of the mail-merge codes.

Is there any way to convert the WordPerfect files so that they retain similar merge functionality in the `.docx` format?